# Javascript - Trouble converting date format to pretty format

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following date format coming from the database:

```
Tue, 01 Nov 2011 15:58:56 -0400
```

What I'm trying to do is convert that to 'pretty' style like "2 months ago". We have [pretty.js](http://ejohn.org/files/pretty.js) already loaded as a dependency and I'd like to be able to just call (* please note I need this to work specifically in safari):

```
prettyDate(someDate)
```

So far I can't get anything to output. It looks like the plugin wants ISO format? I've tried a few simple conversions but to no avail. I don't really think I should need to do much complex parsing here, am I missing something simple I can do to get my date to ISO, to pretty?

Thanks a lot for any thoughts.

Comment: Could you get the date to come from the database in a less-human friendly, but more machine-friendly format? (e.g. UNIX timestamp)

Comment: You could use http://www.datejs.com/ to convert that string to a JavaScript date object

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/d832r/)

When I changed to

```
    var date = new Date(time);
```

I could do

```
<span id="date">Fri, 30 Dec 2011 15:58:56 -0400</span><br/>
<span id="prettydate"></span>
```

using

```
var dateString = $("#date").text();
$("#prettydate").text(prettyDate(dateString))
```

or

```
<span class="jqdate" title="Wed, 28 Dec 2011 15:58:56 -0400"></span>
<span class="jqdate" title="Thu, 29 Dec 2011 15:58:56 -0400"></span>
```

using

```
 $(".jqdate").prettyDate();
```

Tested in Fx10 and Safari 5 on OSX SnowLeopard

```
/*
 * JavaScript Pretty Date
 * Copyright (c) 2011 John Resig (ejohn.org)
 * Licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 */

// Takes an ISO time and returns a string representing how
// long ago the date represents.
function prettyDate(time){
//    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," "));
    var date = new Date(time);
    var diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

     if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 ) {
        alert("Not a date or too old")
        return "";
     }
    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && "just now" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // If jQuery is included in the page, adds a jQuery plugin to handle it as well
  if ( typeof jQuery != "undefined" )
    jQuery.fn.prettyDate = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var date = prettyDate(this.title);
            if ( date )
                jQuery(this).text( date );
        });
    };
    var dateString = new String(Date.parse($("#date").html()));

    $("#prettydate").text(prettyDate(dateString))
});
```

Comment: Hi, so thank for your help here. Unfortunately I'm still getting error in Safari, which it turns out is the browser i'm actually trying to support. I have this working in Chrome how should I tweek the date for safari?  thanks much.

Comment: @Tuddy Can you try my fiddle again, please? I did not even need to parse.

Answer (score 0):

*** Edit, so the below works for Chrome but STILL returns undefined in Safari? Any idea what I can do to get Safari to handle the date correctly as Chrome is??? Thanks much.

So the solution ended up being rather simple. pretty.js, as it's written, returns `undefined` for dates older than 31 days ago (really weird I think...).

I was only using older dates apparently so that was hard to catch.

With a newer date or a few tiny tweeks to the code you can simply do:

```
`prettyDate("Fri, 30 Dec 2011 15:58:56 -0400")`
```

and it works just fine, no need to convert the date format.

Thanks